# Why does SonarQube reopen issues marked as Won't Fix?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

In our organization, we are using SonarQube 5.6 with C# plugin 5.3.1 and every issue we mark as Won't Fix gets reopened next time analysis runs. Sometimes, when the analysis runs again the issues get marked as Won't Fix (as manually marked before). We are trapped in a circle. Any ideas?